# Positioning text in the middle of a gallery so that it's responsive

Tags: css, gallery, positioning, responsive, title

how do I position a title on top of a gallery , like in the picture below.

I'm using a shortcode for the gallery, which comes with my theme.

I was able to do it using position:absolute; and top and bottom values, then center it with display:block; and margin:0 auto;. However, when I change the size of the screen it get's all out of whack.

the html is

```
<div class="gallery-column">
[shortcode goes here]
<h2>Title goes here</h2>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to keep an element centered both horizontally and vertically is with **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

All you need on the parent element is:

- `display: flex` to treat the element as a flexbox
- `align-items: center` for vertical alignment
- `justify-content: center` for horizontal alignment
- a fixed `height` (to create the padding) - `100vh` for a full screen

This can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery-column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-column">
  <div class="centered">
    <h2>Centered Element</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The element in question will remain at the exact center of the page, regardless of screen resizes.

In your case you'll also want a `z-index` to ensure that the element stays on top.
`z-index: 1` should suffice.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your quick response. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work as it is, the text remains below the gallery. Do the elements within the "gallery-column" div need to have a specific setting for display:?

Comment: Actually, it shrinks down the gallery and aligns it to the left, and it puts the h2 on the right side of the gallery. The h2 is vertically aligned, but it's not in the center of the gallery and the gallery is no longer full width. I feel very close to the answer

Comment: I got it to work! I had removed the position:absolute command and when i placed it back in, it all worked.

Comment: Yep, you won't want `position: absolute` applied in conjunction with this solution.